# loop through lists, finding minimum value greater than previous minimum

Tags: python, list

A simple problem.

I have a list of lists, and I am looking to find the minimum value in each list that is greater than the previous minimum.

The lists are individually sorted, and for the first list I'm just looking for the minimum value.

e.g:

```
my_list = [[3, 5, 8, 14, 18, 28, 30],
           [4, 6, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 22, 26],
           [2, 11, 21, 24, 32],
           [1, 10, 12, 16, 20, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 34]]
```

And the expected output would be:

```
[3, 4, 11, 12]
```

Comment: What's the expected output for e.g. `[[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]`, i.e. when there is no minimum in a subsequent list which is greater than the minimum in the previous list?

Comment: Good point, not expecting it to happen in this case so @zondo 's ValueError works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty readable:

```
minimums = []
minimum = None
for sublist in my_list:
    try:
        minimum = min(x for x in sublist if minimum is None or x > minimum)
        minimums.append(minimum)
    except ValueError: # No numbers greater than minimum
        # Error handling
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the built-in [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function since each `list` is already sorted:

```
result = []
first = my_list[0][0]
result.append(first)
for val in my_list[1:]:
    try:
        first = next(el for el in val if el > first)
        result.append(first)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```
curr_min = min(my_list[0])
minimums = [curr_min]
for l in my_list[1:]:
    curr_min = min(filter(lambda x: (x > curr_min), l))
    minimums.append(curr_min)
```

If `filter` returns an empty list, `min` is going to raise a `ValueException`